# Linux Kernel Compiltaion Fails Without Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to add new system call to linux kernel but it fails without giving me any error here is the last lines before it stops.
My Kernel Version: `5.15.0`

Kernel Version I am installing: `5.17.4` & `x86_64`

```
  CC      kernel/iomem.o
  CC      kernel/rseq.o
  CC      kernel/watch_queue.o
  CHK     kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz
  GEN     kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz
  AR      kernel/built-in.a
  CC [M]  kernel/kheaders.o
```

after these lines it just stops, no error no warning.

Comment: Have you tried to build **original** kernel, without your modifications? If unmodified kernel compiles successfully, then for resolve your problem we need to know which modifications you have done.

Comment: How do you know it didn't succeed?

Comment: @stark Normally it takes 2-3 hours but it just tool 4 minutes

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did not try that but I just added basic system call nothing fancy

Comment: make doesn't rebuild targets that are already built.

Comment: "I did not try that but I just added basic system call nothing fancy" - As noted by stark, `make` just rebuilds those files, which depends on your modifications. What is the **problem** you **ask** us to help you with?

Comment: I tried without adding anything, stuck in the same place again @Tsyvarev